# Probability of (1 + min(X,Y))/(1 + min(X,Z))?

Tags: statistics

I have been trying to derive the probability $\Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + \min \left( {X,Y} \right)}}{{1 + \min \left( {X,Z} \right)}} < c} \right]$, where X, Y, and Z are independent and follow exponential distribution with parameters $λ_x$, $λ_y$, and $λ_z$, respectively. c here is a constant. What I did is briefly as follows:

$
\Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + \min \left( {X,Y} \right)}}{{1 + \min \left( {X,Z} \right)}} < c} \right] \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)\\
 = \Pr \left[ {X < Y,X < Z} \right]\\
 + \Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + X}}{{1 + Z}} < c} \right]\Pr \left[ {X < Y,X > Z} \right]\\
 + \Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + Y}}{{1 + X}} < c} \right]\Pr \left[ {X > Y,X < Z} \right]\\
 + \Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + Y}}{{1 + Z}} < c} \right]\Pr \left[ {X > Y,X > Z} \right]            \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2),$

from which I can obtain a closed-form expression. However, when I do simulation to verify my analytic result, I get
[image]

where the red curve is from analysis. I don't know why there is a gap between the results.
Do you think that going from (1) to (2) is problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=(\frac{1 + \min \left( {X,Y} \right)}{1 + \min \left( {X,Z} \right)} < c)$. You have define four events:
\begin{align}
A_1&=(X < Y,X < Z)\\
A_2&=(X < Y,X > Z)\\
A_3&=(X > Y,X < Z)\\
A_3&=(X > Y,X > Z)\\
\end{align}
and then wrote \begin{align}
Pr(B)&=\sum_{i=1}^4P(B|A_i)P(A_i)\\
\end{align}
For $i=1$ you then write
\begin{align}
P(B|A_1)P(A_1)&=P(\frac{1 + \min \left( {X,Y} \right)}{1 + \min \left( {X,Z} \right)} < c|A_1)P(A_1)\\
&=P(\frac{1 + \min \left( {X,Y} \right)}{1 + \min \left( {X,Z} \right)} < c|X < Y,X < Z)P(X < Y,X < Z)\\
&=P(1 < c|X < Y,X < Z)P(X < Y,X < Z)\\
&=1\times P(X < Y,X < Z)\\
\end{align}
which is correct only if $c>1$ if $c\leq1$ then this first term is zero not one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I forgot to mention that in our problem, c is always greater than 1. Hence, the first term is ok. However, I'm not sure that the last three terms, $P(B|A_i)P(A_i)$ for $i \ge 2$, can be like those in equation (2) or not? Can the conditions be removed?
Thank you.

Comment: I see. The rest of your calculations are all correct, i.e you can let the conditions take effect as you do. Would you like to share those derivations you did not show us here?

Comment: Sure.


${I_1} = \Pr \left[ {X < \min \left( {Y,Z} \right)} \right] = \Pr \left[ {X < W} \right]\\
 = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{F_X}\left( w \right){f_W}\left( w \right)dw} \\
 = 1 - \left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}} \right){\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _x}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}} \right)^{ - 1}}$



where Z is also exponential distributed with parameter $\frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}$.

Comment: ${I_{21}} = \Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + X}}{{1 + Z}} \le {2^{2{R_0}}}} \right] = \Pr \left[ {X \le {2^{2{R_0}}} - 1 + {2^{2{R_0}}}Z} \right]\\
 = \int\limits_0^\infty  {{F_X}\left( {{2^{2{R_0}}} - 1 + {2^{2{R_0}}}z} \right){f_Z}\left( z \right)dz} \\
 = 1 - {e^{\frac{{1 - {2^{2{R_0}}}}}{{{\lambda _x}}}}}\lambda _z^{ - 1}{\left( {\frac{{{2^{2{R_0}}}}}{{{\lambda _x}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}} \right)^{ - 1}}$

Comment: ${I_{22}} = \Pr \left[ {X < Y,X > Z} \right]\\
 = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\Pr \left[ {Y > x,Z < x} \right]} {f_X}\left( x \right)dx\\
 = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\Pr \left[ {Y > x} \right]\Pr \left[ {Z < x} \right]} {f_X}\left( x \right)dx\\
 = \frac{1}{{{\lambda _x}}}\left( {{{\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _x}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}}} \right)}^{ - 1}} - {{\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _x}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}} \right)}^{ - 1}}} \right)
$

Comment: $I_{31}$, $I_{32}$, and $I_{41}$ can be derived by following the same above procedures. Let V=max(Y,Z), whose PDF is given by ${f_V}\left( v \right) = \frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}}{e^{\frac{{ - v}}{{{\lambda _y}}}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}{e^{\frac{{ - v}}{{{\lambda _z}}}}} - \left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}} \right){e^{ - v\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _y}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _z}}}} \right)}}$. Then, $I_{42}$ can be derived as follows:

Comment: ${I_{42}} = \Pr \left[ {X > \max \left( {Y,Z} \right)} \right] = \Pr \left[ {X > V} \right]\\
 = 1 - \Pr \left[ {X < V} \right] = 1 - \int\limits_0^\infty  {{F_X}\left( v \right){f_V}\left( v \right)dv}$

Comment: $ = \lambda _{{R_k}D}^{ - 1}{\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _{S{R_k}}}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _{{R_k}D}}}}} \right)^{ - 1}} + \lambda _{{R_k}E}^{ - 1}{\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _{S{R_k}}}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _{{R_k}E}}}}} \right)^{ - 1}}\\
 - \left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _{{R_k}D}}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _{{R_k}E}}}}} \right){\left( {\frac{1}{{{\lambda _{S{R_k}}}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _{{R_k}D}}}} + \frac{1}{{{\lambda _{{R_k}E}}}}} \right)^{ - 1}}$

Comment: I guess the gap between analytic and simulation results come from the fact that I have ignored the conditional probabilities, i.e.,
I have used $\Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + X}}{{1 + Z}} < c} \right]$ instead of $\Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + X}}{{1 + Z}} < c|{A_2}} \right]$

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the probability by integrating the joint pdf like this

$\Pr \left[ {\frac{{1 + \min \left( {X,Y} \right)}}{{1 + \min \left( {X,Z} \right)}} < c} \right] = \int\limits_{z = 0}^{z = \infty } {\int\limits_{x = 0}^{x =  - 1 + c + c*z} {\int\limits_{y = 0}^{y = \infty } {{f_{X,Y,Z}}\left( {x,y,z} \right)dydxdz} } }  + \int\limits_{z = 0}^{z = \infty } {\int\limits_{x =  - 1 + c + c*z}^{x = \infty } {\int\limits_{y = 0}^{y =  - 1 + c + c*z} {{f_{X,Y,Z}}\left( {x,y,z} \right)dydxdz} } } $

This is for $c>1$